# Zero Divisors in a Product of Rings

Tags: ring-theory

In a product of rings for example Z/3 x Z/6 how does one identify zero divisors?  Do you find them with respect to addition or multiplication and what would the Cayley table look like for it? I am so confused.

Comment: A zero divisor is any element of the form $(a,b)$ where either  $a$ or $b$ is a zero divisor. For example, if $a$ is a zero divisor, then there is some $a'$ such that $aa'=0$ so that $$(a,b)(a',0)=(aa',b0)=(0,0)$$

Comment: does it necessarily have to be (a',0) to lead to b0 and eventually 0, or could it be  (a,b)(a',c) = (aa',bc) = (0,0)? @Crostul

Comment: You should write out how multiplication works in a product of rings, if you do that then you will see that your question is very easy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zero divisor in $R$ is a nonzero element  $a\in R$ such that there exists $b\neq 0$ so that $ab=0$. If $R = R_1 \times R_2$ is a product of rings, then it's easy to show that $(a_1, a_2)\in R$ is a zero divisor iff one of these two conditions holds:

$*$ at least one of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are zero divisors

$*$ $a_1 = 0$ xor $a_2 = 0$

Therefore, as $\Bbb{Z}_3$ has no zero divisors (it's a field) and $\Bbb{Z}_6$ has $2$, $3$, and $4$ as zero divisors, your ring has $7$ zero divisors meeting the second condition, and $9$ meeting the first condition (these two groups of zero divisors have $3$ in common, namely $(0, 2)$, $(0, 3)$, and $(0,4)$, giving us a total of $13$).

Comment: isn't the answer 14? So say for the zero divisor we have the element (x,y) in this ring. So multiply (x,y) by (z,w) = (0,0) by definition. Now we know the zero divisors in Z/6 are 2,3,4 and the possible elements of x are 0,1,2. When X=1 or 2 we know Z Must be 0, that means 3 can't be zero, so the possible values for y are 0,2,3,4. So we have 8 elements now in total. For x=0 y can be any value from 0 to 5. 8+6 = 14

Comment: There are $13$, actually, but thanks for pointing out that I made a mistake (I miscounted the number of elements meeting the second condition).

Comment: why is there 13?

Comment: I have 14, namely; (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5), (1,0), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,0), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4). None of them are the same and they all follow the rules of a zero divisor

Comment: I was unaware that some conventions considered $0$ to be a zero divisor, but that appears to be common--so you're right.

Comment: Yeah it confused me for ages but the definition is ab=0 with a in the Ring and b != 0 so yeah (0,0) is a zero divisor